# How to compare if BigDecimal value is inside a range in a query?

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, bigdecimal

Lets say that I have to check in a query if a value is inside a range, and this value is BigDecimal in Java. The values inside the database are numbers(with two decimals). The ideia is above...but I don´t know the right way and to make it a little worst, I don´t have access to test the query apart. I´m using jpa extended repository, so probably I need to write my own query in this case.

```
@Query("SELECT c "
        + " FROM Taxes c "
        + " WHERE c.minOrderValue <= 'Mvalue' AND c.maxOrderValue >= 'Mvalue' "
)
Optional<TaxesRR> getTaxes(@Param("Mvalue") BigDecimal Mvalue);
```

Comment: Replace `'Mvalue'` with `:Mvalue` at the minimum. Not sure if BigDecimal needs any special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

That´s how it´s worked for me. Any other solution is still appreciated.

```
@Query("SELECT c "
        + " FROM ConjuntoTaxasRetencaoRapida c "
        + " WHERE c.valorMinimoPorteFaturamento <= ?1 "
        + " AND c.valorMaximoPorteFaturamento > ?2")
Optional<ConjuntoTaxasRetencaoRapida> obterTaxasRR(BigDecimal valorProjetadoMes, BigDecimal valorProjetadoMesConsolidado);
```